# how detect deprecated functions in android apps

Tags: android, deprecated

how detect deprecated method in android application? which resource is needed, for example class files.. 
My problem is the derecated error is reported in local eclipse but not reported in server for same source. Then what should I check for this problem? please help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really clear.

If Eclipse says the method is deprecated, then it is.
The documentation often tells you what is the new and better way to do what the deprecated method did.

In android doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), you can choose the target version on the top of the list on the left, so you should check the doc for the version you are targeting.

It might be acceptable for you to keep a deprecated method if you absolutely need it and want your min version to be an old one. You can also check the support package that provide you compatibility functions of newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Toaster a bit, deprecated functions are those that are currently supported but may not be supported by future versions. In simpler words, current android versions such KitKat (4.4) will be able to run that function but another update may find that function doesn't exist anymore.

The eclipse gives us `warning` not show `problem` that this particular version is working fine now but may be removed in the future releases, so change that function with a function that is not `depcrecated` and will certainly be present in future versions so that your app may work properly even in case or an OS update.

As far as problem showing the deprecated functions on your server is concerned, i don't know it. Although you might not need it, if you upgrade your functions, but if you do then post a different question and i am sure someone will be able to help you. Happy Coding!!!